# Permutation of statues in a row.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the number of ways in which 5 red statues, 4 blue statues and 4 green statues can be arranged in a row such that

1. The blue statues never stand with the green ones and
2. The number of blue statues minus number the number of green statues standing before any green statue must be greater than 0.
3. Consider statues of same colour to be identical.

My approach :

1. Without constraints : 13! = A1
2. Adding constraint 1 : A1 - (number of ways in which blue and green ones are together) = A2
3. Adding constraint 2 : (no idea) A3
4. Adding constraint 3 : A3/(4! × 4 !× 5!) = A4

Answer = A4. 
I need help with verifying my steps and the step 2 and 3 problem.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Well, as the statues are identical (save for color) your unconstrained number is much too high.  You just need to choose $5$ slots out of thirteen to place the red ones and then $4$ slots out of the remaining eight for the blue, so $A_1=\binom {13}5  \times \binom 84=90090$.

Comment: @lulu statues of same color are considered identical is property 3.  He was going to be worried about that last instead of first, so your comment is unwarranted.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Ah, good point.

Comment: Properties 2 and 3 should remind us of [catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), but I'm not sure how to mesh that with property 1 at first glance.  My initial reaction is unfortunately to brute force the count... a computer program could easily cycle through all 90090 arrangements of 5 a's, 4 b's and 4 c's, or more easily all $3^{13}=1594323$ length $13$ strings of a's, b's and c's, and check properties 1 and 2 for each (*as well as checking number of each a,b,c to make sure its 5,4,4 respectively*)...